# Плагин для слайдера js с минимальным количеством DOM элементов

Tags: javascript, slider

На сайте использую skick.js для слайдеров продукции. Их на странице 8 слайдеров по 5 слайдов(товары) и слик создает много DOM элементов, на что потом ругается  google pageSpeed Insights . Есть ли аналог слик в котором меньше элементов DOM создается, или придётся писать на нативе?

Comment: а что значит "много DOM элементов"?

Comment: Слайдеров полно всяких, "натив" на количество элементов в DOM никак не влияет.